# Upvoting every correct answer at own questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, up-votes

Is it common practice or 'decent' to upvote every answer at own questions?

I mean, the people taking the time finding an answer and typing it, should get some points I would say? As long as the answer is correct of course.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I mean, the people taking the time finding an answer and typing it, should get some points I would say?

No, not generally. People are expected to answer anyway. They only should get upvotes for *good* and *correct* contributions. "taking the time finding an answer" doesn't always imply that it's a good answer that deserves upvotes. I've seen enough users type up worthless garbage that was upvoted anyway because "they just tried to help".

> As long as the answer is correct of course.

**This is the crucial point**. Don't blindly upvote people for "This doesn't work, but here's an upvote for trying to help". This won't help anybody, giving a false impression to visitors who think that an upvoted answer actually works, and it encourages people to post wrong answers without trying, since they might score reputation from them after all.

So, **only upvote answers that are helpful** when you see them. Do not upvote every answer you get, if you're unsure about how it helps solve your problem or if it's just plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the comment ... Until now I upvote also only answers that are correct, even if some other answers are more elaborate. Of course if an answer is incorrect, or is not a real answer but more a remark not driving to a solution I don't upvote.